# Ngfor and interpolation in angular

Tags: angular, interpolation, ngfor

```
<div class="container latestNew" *ngFor="let link of links$ | async">
  <div class="col">{{ link.title }}</div>
  <div class="col">{{ links$[0].title }}</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me why the *link.title* works but *links$[0].title* does not work?

Comment: `links$` is an *observable* (that's why you have to resolve the value with `| async`), so `links$[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: even when I use like this {{ links$[0].title  | async } }. it still not works

Comment: It's not clear why you'd think it would, `links$` is still an observable, so `links$[0]` is still `undefined`. If you want access to the array, do e.g. `links$ | async as links` as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`links$` is an `Observable<Array<T>>` means it doesn't contain any value, it is just a subscriber to allow catch a value from `Subject<Array<T>>` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject). The expression `let in of link$ | async` means that indicates this block *ngFor must be waited until new array is coming from `Subject` by `next(new Array<T>[])`, it will be set into `link` per each received object.

In your case, I suppose you call `HttpClient` and declare a line below in your `Component`

```ts
links$: Observable<Array<Link>>
ngOnInit(): void {
   // Retrieve a links list from API
   this.links$ = this.httpClient.get<Array<Link>>('http://localhost/api/links')
}
```

With this code, you want to ensure the `links$` data is retrieved from API before rendering HTML. So Angular provides to you a expression `| async` to make this be `awaiter` until your API has done. `let link` in an expression is helping you to access each `link` in retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because `links$` is an `Observable` and not an array. What you've written can work if firstly you extract the data from it (after are emitted):

```
<div class="container latestNew" *ngFor="let link of links$ | async as links">
  <div class="col">{{ link.title }}</div>
  <div class="col">{{ links[0].title }}</div>
</div>
```